# Is it possible to run an Ansible playbook from a Chef AWS/Opworks cookbook?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, ansible, chef-infra, aws-cloudformation

I try to figure out if it's possible to create a Chef cookbook that ssh into an Ansible server and run some Ansible cookbook from AWS Opworks on the current *node*

I think of a script that I can put in a execute like this :

```
define :foobar_magento2_deploy  do
  release_path = node[:app_release_path]

  execute 'Ansible playbook' do
    command "ssh -i key ansible-server 'ansible-playbook arg1 arg2'"
  end
end
```

Do you think it's possible ? Is there some caveats ? Hints ?

Edit from @coderanger answer:

```
define :foobar_magento2_deploy  do
  release_path = node[:app_release_path]

  execute 'Ansible playbook' do
    command "git clone ansible-playbook"
    command "cd ansible-playbook"
    command "ansible-playbook -l localhost playbook.yml"
  end
end
```

Comment: Seems interesting: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/ansible-pull.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So a couple of things:

1. OpsWorks Stacks is dangerously out of date and using it should be considered highly suspect.
2. I don't actually recognize that `define` block thing in there, maybe that's an older OpsWorks syntax?
3. You can definitely run an Ansible playbook from Chef code, but I would probably go a little simpler than you have there. Probably just run `ansible-playbook` locally and aim it at localhost.

Comment: You can only have one `command`, you probably to use a `git` resource for the clone and use the `cwd` property of the `execute` resource to set the working directory.

Comment: Then I don’t know what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: The most recent update to it is still Chef 12, which went End Of Life in April. We (the Chef community) do not maintain or support it anymore. As such, it's an active security risk.